# Timestamp with Expiration Date

Tags: php, pdo, timestamp

Im doing my project and its all about reservation system . But i cant find any solution maybe someone can explain and make a clear example about making an expiration date based on what's the user given date.

Comment: @TomLord 
$d1 = strtotime("10:30pm April 15,2014");
if($d1 == date("Y-m-d")){
echo 'expired';
}
else{
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
echo "The time and date is " . date("F j, Y h:i:sa");
}

this one but what im trying to do is my $d1 should not be fixed

Comment: So your question is about how to declare a variable base on user input; your "expiration date" code works fine? How will users be submitting this data - though a web form? What have you done already; what's not working? Please provide enough information for people to actually help.